# git fetch/pull on origin repositiory

Tags: git

I have two repositories: one is on my PC and the second is on my laptop. I would like to publish my changes from my laptop now so that they are confirmed on my PC too.

I use LAN to share my files as read-only and I am thinking what is disadvange of committing changes from laptop and later pulling them on my PC, instead of using push from my my laptop directly? Is it a bad way?

Comment: Can you give some more details? What do you mean by "origin on my PC" and "laptop (remote)"?

Comment: On the beginning, I have created a repository on my PC, so this is an origin. As remote I mean the new repository created on my laptop.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the terms origin and remote with respect to git.

Comment: I removed the "origin" and "remote" terms from my post now in order to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you simply want to keep the repo on your desktop and laptop in sync. I would suggest using a bare repo on your desktop as your remote and use that repo to sync both the repos on your desktop and laptop from that bare repo.

A `remote` is simply a [bare repo](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server) from which you can clone your repo onto any machine.

`origin` is just a name given by convention to the first remote of a repo.

Comment: What if I do not want to use centralized workflow? Should I prepare bare repository too?